# fgets() заменил scanf() и код заработал

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Код выполняет фу-ию **поиск песни**. Имеется массив в массиве и ввод того что нужно искать, **если ввод осуществляется через fgets() программа не работает**  если **через scanf() все работает**. Вопрос заключается в следующем, почему так происходит с fgets() и scanf() и для чего нужна звездочка в глобальной переменной char *tracks[]?

**Вот весь код**

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <string.h>
```

*Почему здесь здвездоча а точнее указатель ведь это глобальная переменная*

```
        char *tracks[] = {
        "Я оставил свое сердце в Гарвардской медицинской  школе",
        "Ньюарк, Ньюарк - город, полный чудес town",
        "Танец с мужланом",
        "Отсюда и до роддома",
        "Девченка с острова Иводзима",
        };

        void find_track(char search_for[])
        {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(strstr(tracks[i], search_for))
              printf("Песня номер %i: %s\n", i, tracks[i]);
        }
        }
        int main() {
        char search_for[80];//фу-ия в стеке и яв-ся
        printf("Искать: ");
```

*здесь и начинается суть вопроса весь код в принципе исправен*

```
      fgets(search_for, 80, stdin);
```

*строка ниже считает количество введенных символов отнимает 1
  и получается что она добавляет к последнему адресу в массиве \0*

```
     search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = "\0";
```

*fgets почему то не работает и добавляет новый символ в коде
  с scanf такой проблемы нет *

```
     printf("fgets() приняла: %s;\nДлинна строки: %lu;", search_for, strlen(search_for));
```

*Код с scanf() работает но поиск в таком случае будетосуществляется только по одному слову*

```
      scanf("%79s", search_for);

      find_track(search_for);
      return 0;
      }
```

Comment: Компилятор вам указал на ошибку здесь: `search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = "\0";` Вы просто проигнорировали его диагностику?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему здесь здвездоча а точнее указатель ведь это глобальная переменная
>
> ```
>     char *tracks[] = {
> ```

Глобальная переменная или нет — ничего не меняет: это определение массива указателей на `char` (символы). В Си в большинстве случаев указатель на `char` интерпретируется как нуль-терминированная строка. Без звёздочки это был бы просто массив символов (или строка).

> строка ниже считает количество введенных символов отнимает 1 и
>   получается что она добавляет к последнему адресу в массиве \0
>
> ```
>  search_for[strlen(search_for)-1] = "\0";
> ```
>
> *fgets почему то не работает и добавляет новый символ в коде с scanf такой проблемы нет

Основная ошибка: вокруг `'\0'` должны быть одинарные кавычки, которые означают **символ** (символьную константу). Двойные кавычки означают **строку**. Т.о. в данном примере ты берёшь **адрес** константной строки и присваиваешь его нижний байт символу, соответственно с высокой долей вероятности он получает мусорное значение. Наверняка компилятор указывал на это warning'ом, к которому стоило бы прислушаться. Также можно записать просто `0` (без кавычек) — в Си эти две константы абсолютно идентичны.

Кстати, символа новой строки может и не быть, если ввод завершился EOF'ом или превысил длину буфера, так что кроме прочего стоит проверять, что ты заменяешь именно '\n', а не что-то ещё...

Answer (score 1):

Ну и к ответу @Fat-Zer добавлю, что `scanf` при `%s` считывает *одно слово*. Если хочется читать строку - нужно что-то типа

```
scanf("%79[^\n]",s);
```